# Swift - CoreData Faulting

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have object with name `Coctail` and his relationship(many-to-many) with name `Tag`.
[image]

I want to get object `Coctail` from database (I use `NSFetchedResultsController`) and print his tags. But when I try get tags like this 'coctail.tags' I get this

> Relationship 'tags' fault on managed object...

Also when I try to get counts of tags ('coctail.tags.count') I get 0.

I don't know what code you need.

Comment: Did you check any similar questions and answers? Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876234/coredata-relationship-fault) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769717/ios-core-data-relationship-faults)?

Comment: @tahavath Yep! Already checked

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878384/5779168) will help you.

Comment: @tahavath it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the persistent properties of `Coctail` object to use latest values from the persistent store. To do this, you need use [`refresh(_ object: NSManagedObject, mergeChanges flag: Bool)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506224-refreshobject) method with `true` flag.

[Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH18-SW1).